# How to run command after entering postgres

Tags: shell, shell-script, terminal, chroot, postgresql

I am trying to execute `ls` after opening a new *Guake* tab and logging into `postgres`.

```
guake -n guake -e 'sudo -i -u postgres && ls'
```

The command successful opens a new tab then prompts me for my password and logins into `postgres`, but it does not execute ls once in `postgres`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check manual page for [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)? The third synopsis example shows

```
sudo [...] [-u user name ] [VAR=value] -i | -s [command]
```

the `command` part is the thing you are looking for. It is the command that is executed after changing user to the required one.

This fits exactly into your example like this:

```
sudo -u postgres -i ls
```

joining everything together with your original task:

```
guake -n guake -e 'sudo -u postgres -i ls'
```